# Проверка состояния сервиса с помощью consul

Tags: vault

Написал compose файл, в нем создается 3 образа с консулом в режиме сервер, 1 образ в режиме клиент, и одно хранилище vault. В вебморде видно что сервера все друг друга видят ( находятся в одном дата центре), клиент и vault тоже видно. Но как только я добавил `healthcheck` мне пишет:

> Head "http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/health": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

В документации написано что проверку vault можно делать по пути host:port/v1/sys/health с помощью get запроса. Однако оно пишет данную ошибку. Я добавил заголовки для авторизации с помощью стандартного токена vault, однако все равно получаю данную ошибку. Листинг файла с сервисом и проверкой:

```
 {
        "service": {
                "name": "vault",
                "tags": ["vault"],
                "address": "localhost",
                "port": 8200
        },
        "check": {
                "id": "vault",
                "name": "Check vault health",
                "service_id": "vault",
                "header": {"accept": ["*/*"],"X-Vault-Token": ["myroot"]},
                "http": "http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/health",
                "method": "HEAD",
                "interval": "30s",
                "timeout": "5s"
        }
}
```

И сам `docker-compose.yaml` файл:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  consul-agent-server-1:
    image: consul:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: consul-server-1
    command: 'agent -server -ui -node=consul-server-1 -bootstrap-expect=3 -client=0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
  consul-agent-server-2:
    image: consul:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: consul-server-2
    command: 'agent -server -node=consul-server-2 -join=consul-server-1 -bootstrap-expect=3'
  consul-agent-server-3:
    image: consul:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: consul-server-3
    command: 'agent -server -node=consul-server-3 -join=consul-server-1 -bootstrap-expect=3'
  consul-agent-client-1:
    image: consul:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: consul-client-1
    command: 'agent -node=consul-client-1 -join=consul-server-1 -config-file=/consul/services/'
    volumes:
      - './services/:/consul/services/:ro'
  vault-1:
    image: vault
    restart: always
    container_name: vault-storage-1
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:8200
      - VAULT_API_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:8200
      - VAULT_ADDRESS=http://0.0.0.0:8200
      - VAULT_UI=true
      - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с таким вопросом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем удалось проблему решить следующим способом:

1. В docker-compose создать отдьльную сеть, и каждому сервису выделить свой ip.
2. В файле с проверкой заменить localhost на ip сервиса.

В целом это рабочий вариант